# Specify UTF-8 encoding in Vimrc

Tags: encoding

Since Vim and NeoVIM defaults to UTF-8, does it make any sense to specify the same option explicitly in vimrc? set encoding="utf-8"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be `set encoding=utf-8`, no quotes.  `set encoding="utf-8"` would be an error because `"utf-8"` would be considered a comment, thus it would be the same as `set encoding=`.

---

Vim does not actually default [`'encoding'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27encoding%27) to UTF-8.  It defaults to latin1, but will change based on the locale of your environment.

However, since changing `'encoding'` at runtime is dangerous (as in, it can cause a crash -- see below), Neovim decided to *only* support `encoding=utf-8`.  This vastly simplifies the code, since now everything is working with UTF-8 internally, and only has to encode/decode when interfacing with the outside world (saving files in specific encodings, converting input from the locale's encoding, etc.).

IMHO, it's a good idea to always put `set encoding=utf-8` in your vimrc.  It automatically enables saner encoding detection settings for [`'fileencodings'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'fileencodings') and supports any characters that you'll need to store.

---

The crash example I gave in 2009 when I [suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/up1KslPRGzk/9xwHeIb6WWgJ) changing Vim's default value for `'encoding'`:

```
vim -u NONE --cmd 'set enc=utf8 list' -c 'let &lcs="nbsp:".nr2char("8215")'
:put =nr2char("160")
:set enc=latin1
```

Comment: What about "vim --help"? That's probably terminal settings that need changing but I only managed to output help contents with all language specific characters cut out. For example 'ŻÓŁTY' => 'TY'